# Understanding namespaces

Tags: 8

I am new to namespaces and I am practicing with Drupal 8. I have created a custom module and have installed the contrib, devel.

Inside my module, I have defined a block.

```php
namespace Drupal\twitter_pull\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a block for executing PHP code.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "twitter_pull_tweets_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Twitter Tweets")
 * )
 */
class TweetsBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * Builds and returns the renderable array for this block plugin.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A renderable array representing the content of the block.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder
   */
  public function build() {
    dpm(array('this','is','a','test'));
    return 'this is a block';
  }
}
```

It works fine. Why do I have access to the devel functions? Where in my code do I include the namespace for devel that I should have access to `dpm()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight from the PHP [Global space](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) docs:

> Without any namespace definition, all class and function definitions are placed into the global space - as it was in PHP before namespaces were supported. Prefixing a name with \ will specify that the name is required from the global space even in the context of the namespace.

Devel's `dpm()` is declared in 'Global space', and since there's no other `dpm()` function declared in your namespace, the 'global' one is used (no need for the preceeding `\`).

Comment: Correct, additionally, functions are special and different from classes. Classes in the global namespace  *must* be referenced with a leading \, while functions automatically fall back to the global namespace. What is however confusing is that if a function is not found (neither global or current namespace), then the error will include the current namespace.

Comment: Very interesting. I thought namespaces were a requirement in drupal 8, but I see that the devel.module file has no namespaces and thats where the dpm function is located. Are namespaces only not a requirement when located in the .module file?

Comment: 'Required' perhaps isn't the right word...Drupal uses a PSR-4 autoloader to discover classes based on a strict naming convention (PHP will be told to look for `Drupal\my_module\SomeClass` in `/path/to/my_module/src/SomeClass.php`, for example). For classes that aren't auto-discovered by way of annotation (like plugins) they don't _theoretically_ have to be namespaced at all; PHP/Drupal wouldn't care as long as the class names are unique within the global space. Of course polluting the global space is bad, and modularising one's code is always a good thing, so always use it for classes...

Comment: ...as far as functions go, I've yet to come across a framework that namespaces functions. I'm sure there are valid edge-cases for it, but in an OO architecture it just doesn't make much sense. D8 is still a mash of procedural and OO code, so you'll still find a lot of globally scoped functions. The hook system doesn't lend itself too well to scoped functions either, the whole thing's a lot easier with global ones, so you could go so far as to say D8 has a requirement to _not_ use namespacing for functions